# Output two different kinds of sql tables on same form

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: computers, and equipment.  Both tables have all of the same information; make, model, location, etc.  However, computers have two extra fields, processor, and ram.

I want to create a location report that displays all of the computers, and all other equipment in a specific room and display it in a table.  Obviously the equipment will be blank for RAM and Processor.

I am having a hard time figuring out a query.  If I use union, I get an error that the tables don't match.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `union` specifying the exact same amount of columns.

Like this:

```
select make, model, location, processor, ram
  from computers
 union all
select make, model, location, '', ''
  from equipment
```

Please note the two extra "fake" columns on the latter select.

Comment: What if I want the extra computer fields to display even though they will be blank for the regular equipment?

Comment: @Brian: the query I posted will do **exactly** that. Will show `ram` and `processor` for `computers` rows and will show **blank** for `equipment` rows. Try it.